# Magento Checkout Stop refresh

Tags: magento, refresh

I am about to redesign the order reciept (last step in the checkout page after payment).

We use the standard one page checkout. But in order to see the changes i made at the reciept, i do not want the checkout to go to frontpage when i hit refresh.

Is there some way i can make magento stay at the reciept page instead of it automaticly redirects to the frontpage?

I have tryed commented out the SuccessAction in OnepageController.php but that did not help.
Any ideas?

//Simon

Answer (score 1):

As far as it's for temporary testing, you can comment out the line `$session->clear();` in the `successAction()` method from `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`.

Comment: Have try'd that. It still go back to the 1. step in checkout when i refresh the page. I wan't it to stay at the order reciept step.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood which part you were talking about. So in fact, it's not really possible to make Magento go directly to the last step when you refresh the OPC page, because everything there is done with AJAX calls and JS (there is no other way than to start from the beginning each time). Anyway, why don't you use Firebug to test your changes ?

Comment: That's okay. That what i feared and it gives sense. I am currently using Firebug to se some live changes, but still i have to reload the page, and complete several orders to se the correct results :/. But anyways, thanks for you input :)